# Name of the process to project / map / link a landscape photo to terrain data

Tags: geotiff-tiff

A few months back I found a demo of a landscape image where clicking on a point of an image of a mountain range showed where on a map and the elevation of that point. Since then I have not been able to find it again.

I am in the process of taking a large panorama of an area. To the point where the laws of physics limit me to needing to precompute the focal distance for each image

As such I'm hoping to have a way of aligning my image to the GeoTIFF elevation data for the regions to spot discrepancies, and in the feild to help syncronise the mount and calibrate my focuser with common known distance points.

Would any one know what this process might be called or anything similar to it.

Below is an example image of an area I am covering. Its about 114x70km taken at 0.4 arcseconds per pixel on the full scale one for context.
[image: example image]